# iTunesLibrary Swift 5.3 macOS

Tags: swift, ituneslibrary

After reading the documentation and looking through the header files of the iTunesLibrary frameworks I am unable to determine how, or if it's even possible, to manually specify the iTunes/Music library file to read?

The documentation within the header files indicate the system dynamic library loads the 'Default' library.  The only way I have found so far to load another library is to use the +click method to manually choose the library to be used, then quit the Music app and the last chosen library become the default.

Is there not a way to specify a file?  The mediaFolderLocation and musicFolderLocation methods are defined as 'get only' methods.

Answer (score 0):

After lots and lots of research I have determined there is not a way to specify the particular library you want to open.  It automatically refers to the system 'default' library.